# ExtJS image not getting displayed properly

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Is there some way to find out the list of images associated with an example? When i double click some example then the images are coming perfect but while implementing it in my project, I am having lots of image problems. e.g. In the Grid cell-editing example demo, when I implement it in my project then the Sort Ascending, Sort Descending and Columns images are not getting displayed. I tried running this in Chrome and FIrefox but not getting any missing image error/exception/warning as well.

Please let me know about this.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a couple of images, you can right-click the images in the working example and click "Inspect Element". For the grid cell-editing demo, the images are '/resources/themes/images/default/grid/sort_asc.gif', '/resources/themes/images/default/grid/sort_desc.gif', and '/resources/themes/images/default/grid/grid3-hd-btn.gif'. They are referenced in the ext-all.css file, so if the images are missing in your version and you aren't seeing any console errors, your version of the css file might not reference those background images.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If i try to inspect Sort Ascending element, then I am getting this HTML: `<span id="menuitem-1027-textEl" class="x-menu-item-text">Sort Ascending</span>` IT does not informs about the missing image.....right?

Comment: There should be an image tag immediately above that line. If it's there but there are no icons, click the tag and compare what you see to [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/mqt2A.png). Is it the same?